# What is the format for UNIX timestamp of '253402128000000'?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a whole column of timestamp values in UNIX format but I get some values that doesn't look like a normal timestamp format: **253402128000000**

For what I know, a timestamp should look like: 1495245009655

I've tried in miliseconds, nanoseconds and other configurations for Pandas to_datetime but I haven't been able to find a solution that can convert the format.

**EDIT**

My data looks like below and the ValidEndDateTime seems way off.

```
        "ValidStartDateTime": "/Date(1495245009655)/",
        "ValidEndDateTime": "/Date(253402128000000)/",
```

**SOLUTION**

I've accepted the answer below because I can see the date is a "never-end" date as all the values in my dataset that can't be converted is set to the same value: 253402128000000

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: `1495245009655` isn't a valid Unix timestamp.

Comment: It says it's a valid unix time stamp when using a tool like https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ ?

Comment: Not according to the POSIX definition of a timestamp, no. A *true* Unix timestamp is seconds from the epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00. And this is what [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) accepts.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know what timestamp format 1495245009655 is? Would it be epoch?

Comment: It's a timestamp in milliseconds since the epoch. There are all sorts of timestamp formats, down to nanoseconds and probably beyond, but the specific POSIX/Unix format is seconds. To get a proper Unix timestamp, you can divide by 1000 (or 1 million or 1 billion or whatever) using Python's `fromtimestamp()` that I linked above, or by using the `unit` key in `pd.to_datetime()` as in one of the answers below.

Comment: I noticed that there are a lot of formats and I must admit I don't quite understand them yet. Will read up on it and thank you for the explenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment of yours:

> The data I get looks like this: "ValidStartDateTime": "/Date(1495245009655)/", "ValidEndDateTime": "/Date(253402128000000)/",

The numbers appear to be UNIX timestamps in milliseconds and the big "End" one seems to mean "never end", note the special date:

1495245009655 = Sat May 20 2017 01:50:09

253402128000000 = Thu Dec 30 9999 00:00:00

Converted with https://currentmillis.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think it was divided by 1,000,000 becoming 253402128 and calculated.

Which means approximately 44 years ago.

> **Format:** Microseconds (1/1,000,000 second)
>
> **GMT:**  Wed Jan 11 1978 21:28:48 GMT+0000

I used this website as reference: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

The data I get looks like this:

            "ValidStartDateTime": "/Date(1495245009655)/",
            "ValidEndDateTime": "/Date(253402128000000)/",

And the end time can't be before the start time or am i wrong? Is my data incorrect?

It should be the same format.

Comment: @Jacob I think your data is wrong.

Comment: Just as I thought but I wanted to see if any had come over this kind of timestamp but thank you for  your help!

Comment: @Jacob What makes you think it's not the same format? Maybe it's just a huge number intended to mean "never end"?

Comment: Pandas couldn't convert the timestamp therefor I thought it was in a wrong format. 
Taking a second look into my dataset I can see that all the values are the same: 253402128000000 which supports your theory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1495245009655, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2017-05-20 01:50:09.655000')

>>> pd.to_datetime(253402128000000 / 100, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2050-04-19 22:48:00')
```

Comment: I'm using the function already but the output is not correct. It can't be in year  2050

Comment: What is the date should be (approximately)? 1969-05-19?

Comment: It should be around the first datetime value that you used. So around year 2017 +/- 1-2 years